# Accessing reference to a Singleton from Interface, can it be done?

Tags: java, interface, singleton

Suppose you have a Singleton `A` whose `getInstance()` throws some Exceptions.

Further suppose that `A` is used everywhere throughout the program and while `A.getInstance().doSomethingUseful()` is fine, a lot of code inherits from `Constants` interface and i'd like to declare:

`A a = A.getInstance()` in `Constants`, allowing everyone tho implements `Constants` access to `a`.

As expected, though, `Java` complains that method throws Exceptions and as such can't be declared in an interface.

**Is there a workaround around it?**

Comment: What would you *want* to happen if the exceptions were thrown? (And ideally, get rid of this "implementing constants" part... read Effective Java for details.)

Comment: static method in interface? :|

Comment: @amit - my understanding is that static methods in interfaces are allowed in java 8, however, they cannot be inherited:) so that won't help the case here.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have the book, what part should i revisit please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is really not a good idea. You're attempting to tie the lifecycle of that object directly into the structure of the classes implementing that interface.

If you have to use a singleton, then better to reference it explicitly via the `getInstance()` method. It's relatively intuitive. Make your instantiation exceptions runtime if you have to.

Better still is to accept the premise that the singleton pattern is regarded as an [anti-pattern](http://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/singleton-is-an-anti-pattern/) and consider alternatives such as [injection-of-control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: +1 IOC is better because you don't need singletons as such, instead you have classes which happen to have only one instance. When you need to mock the class or later decide you need two instances, no change is required to your code. IMHO, I try to only use stateless singletons defined via enums.

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert the checked exception to unchecked

```
static A getInstanceA2() throws Error
{
    try
    {   return A.getInstance();   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   throw new Error(e);   }
}

interface Constants
{
    A a = getInstanceA2();
}
```

If `getInstane()` fails, interface `Constants` will be broken, and your app probably will crash.

If there are circular dependencies among `A` and `Contants`, `A` may observe some uninitialized static fields in `Constants`